# How can I list the contents of a directory in Python?

Tags: python, path

Can’t be hard, but I’m having a mental block.

Answer (score 346, accepted):

```
import os
os.listdir("path") # returns list
```

Comment: and passing no arguments will list CWD's contents: `os.listdir()` = `os.listdir('.')`

Answer (score 76):

One way:

```
import os
os.listdir("/home/username/www/")
```

[Another way](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```
glob.glob("/home/username/www/*")
```

[Examples found here](http://diveintopython.net/file_handling/os_module.html).

The `glob.glob` method above will not list hidden files.

Since I originally answered this question years ago, [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) has been added to Python. My preferred way to list a directory now usually involves the `iterdir` method on `Path` objects:

```py
from pathlib import Path
print(*Path("/home/username/www/").iterdir(), sep="\n")
```

Comment: Would glob.glob list hidden files (I assume you mean `.XYZ` files in a Unix file-system context), when used with `glob.glob("/home/username/www/.*")` ?

Comment: Yes I mean files beginning with a dot.  The example you gave would work for matching hidden files (and only hidden files).

Comment: I just imported glob and used glob.glob(r'c:\users') but it only returned `['c:\\users']`

Comment: @Musixauce3000: You'll want to do `glob.glob(r'c:\users\*')` (glob it doesn't actually list directories, but expands asterisks and such which accomplishes a similar task).

Comment: Regarding the `pathlib` solution, you can use the `glob` function and then convert it to a list: `list(Path("home/username/www").glob(*))`. It is slightly more readable IMO.

Answer (score 49):

`os.walk` can be used if you need recursion:

```
import os
start_path = '.' # current directory
for path,dirs,files in os.walk(start_path):
    for filename in files:
        print os.path.join(path,filename)
```

Answer (score 19):

`glob.glob` or `os.listdir` will do it.

Comment: `import glob` ENTER `glob.glob(r'c:\users')` ENTER only seems to return `['c:\\users']`. Why is that? I'd like to use glob.glob because as other users have pointed out, it supposedly returns the contents of a directory while also ignoring hidden files. This is important.

Comment: because you have to specify a wildcard with `glob`: `glob.glob(r'c:\users\*')`

Answer (score 15):

The [`os` module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) handles all that stuff.

> `os.listdir(path)`
>
> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. 
>   The list is in arbitrary order. It does not include the special entries '.' and 
>   '..' even if they are present in the directory.
>
> Availability: Unix, Windows.

Answer (score 8):

In Python 3.4+, you can use the new [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) package:

```
from pathlib import Path
for path in Path('.').iterdir():
    print(path)
```

`Path.iterdir()` returns an iterator, which can be easily turned into a `list`:

```
contents = list(Path('.').iterdir())
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Python 3.5, you can use `os.scandir`.

The difference is that it returns file *entries* not names. On some OSes like windows, it means that you don't have to `os.path.isdir/file` to know if it's a file or not, and that saves CPU time because `stat` is already done when scanning dir in Windows:

example to list a directory and print files bigger than `max_value` bytes:

```
for dentry in os.scandir("/path/to/dir"):
    if dentry.stat().st_size > max_value:
       print("{} is biiiig".format(dentry.name))
```

(read an extensive performance-based answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46145070/6451573))

Answer (score 3):

Below code will list directories and the files within the dir. The other one is os.walk

```
def print_directory_contents(sPath):
        import os                                       
        for sChild in os.listdir(sPath):                
            sChildPath = os.path.join(sPath,sChild)
            if os.path.isdir(sChildPath):
                print_directory_contents(sChildPath)
            else:
                print(sChildPath)
```