# List the content of a folder using python

Tags: python, file

Is it possible to output the contents of a folder in python ?
If, say you had a function and you would pass the folder path to its argument?
What would be the simplest way for a beginner to take?

> By "simplest" I mean, without using any modules.

#### Note

Google usually leads me to stackoverflow. Plus I am not looking for generic answers. I am looking for insight based on experience and wit, which I can only find here.

Comment: `os` is default module i.e you don't need to install it manually

Comment: What is a default module? One you don't have to import or one you don't have to download. Because if it's a default module as `math` is, then it's not this I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `os.listdir()` to look at the contents of a directory. It takes the path as an argument, for example:

```
import os

directory = os.listdir('/')
for filename in directory:
  print(filename)
```

prints this for me:

```
bin
home
usr
sbin
proc
tmp
dev
media
srv
etc
lib64
mnt
boot
run
var
sys
lib
opt
root
.dockerenv
run_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `listdir`? Let's try like this way-

```
import os

def ShowDirectory: 
   return os.listdir("folder/path/goes/here")

ShowDirectory()
```

Answer (score 0):

With function.

```
def ListFolder(folder):
    import os
    files = os.listdir(folder)
    print(*files,sep="\n")
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use google first next time...it seems you are looking for this:

[How can I list the contents of a directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759323/how-can-i-list-the-contents-of-a-directory-in-python)

The accepted answer there:

```
import os
os.listdir("path") # returns list
```

Comment: Google usually leads me to stackoverflow. Plus I am not looking for generic answers. I am looking for insight based on experience and wit, which I can only find here.

Comment: which has been already answered in above link i gave you...;) Goodluck