# Python: How to decode file names retrieved from 'dir' command using subprocess?

Tags: python, encoding, subprocess, popen

I am trying to get directory listing on Windows 10 file system using the `subprocess.Popen` function  and `dir` command in Python 3.8.2. To be more specific, I have this piece of code:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['dir'], shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
  print(line.decode('utf-16'))
process.stdout.close()
```

When I run the above in a directory that has file names with Unicode characters (such as "háčky a čárky.txt"), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "error.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(line.decode('utf-16'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 42: truncated data
```

Obviously, the problem is with the encoding. I have tried using 'utf-8' instead of 'utf-16', but with no success. When I remove the `decode('utf-16')` call and use just `print(line)`, I get the following output:

```
b' Volume in drive C is OSDisk\r\n'
b' Volume Serial Number is 9E2B-67E3\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b' Directory of C:\\Users\\asamec\\Dropbox\\DIY\\Python\\AccessibleRunner\\AccessibleRunner\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'05/14/2021  09:19 AM    <DIR>          .\r\n'
b'05/14/2021  09:19 AM    <DIR>          ..\r\n'
b'05/13/2021  09:46 PM             5,697 AccessibleRunner.py\r\n'
b'05/14/2021  09:18 AM               214 error.py\r\n'
b'05/13/2021  05:48 PM             5,642 h\xa0cky a c\xa0rky.txt.py\r\n'
b'               3 File(s)         11,553 bytes\r\n'
b'               2 Dir(s)  230,706,778,112 bytes free\r\n'
```

When I remove the 'utf-16' argument and leave just `print(line.decode())`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "error.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(line.decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 40: invalid start byte
```

So the question is how should I decode the processes' standard output so that I can print the correct characters?

### Update

Running the `chcp 65001` command in the Windows command line before running the python script is the solution. But, the following gives me the same error s above:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['cmd', '/c', 'chcp 65001 & dir'], shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
  print(line.decode('utf-16'))
process.stdout.close()
```

However, when running this same Python script for the second time, it starts to work as the code page is already set to 65001. So the question now is how can I set the Windows console code page not prior to running the Python script, but rather in that Python script?

Comment: There are plenty more [direct ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759323/how-can-i-list-the-contents-of-a-directory-in-python) to get the contents of a directory than trying to parse the `stdout` of `dir` - why mess around with the funny edge cases of this method?

Comment: I am building a simple command line and `dir` is just an example of a command that could be run in that tool.

Comment: What if you use `print(line) ### .decode('utf-16'))`? Please include that info for `"háčky a čárky.txt"` to your [mcve]. For me it's UTF-8 `b'h\xc3\xa1\xc4\x8dky a \xc4\x8d\xc3\xa1rky.txt\r\n'` because my `REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" -v *CP` returns `65001` in `ACP` as well as `OEMCP`; yours could be different… `print(line.decode())` should work.

Comment: @JosefZ I have updated the question to address your suggestions.

Comment: Do you have set the [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable? Mine is `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`.

Comment: Setting the env. var. using `os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = 'utf-8'` gives me error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 40: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@JosefZ suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67533056/686534), the UTF-8 code page must be [set in the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) prior to running the `dir` command. Below is the complete solution for my question:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['chcp', '65001'], shell = True)
process = subprocess.Popen(['dir'], shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
  print(line.decode('utf-8'))
process.stdout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Set console to UTF-8](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) *before* running the script (use `CHCP 65001`):

The script runs smoothly then: `.\SO\67524114.py`

> ```
> Active code page: 65001
> HL~Real~Def.txt
> html.txt
> háčky a čárky.txt
> ```

I can reproduce the issue using the following call:

```
>NUL chcp 852
.\SO\67524114.py
```

> ```
> Active code page: 852
> HL~Real~Def.txt
> html.txt
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\bat\SO\67524114.py", line 7, in <module>
>     print(line.decode('utf-8').strip())
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 1: invalid start byte
> ```

Modified script used for testing:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['cmd', '/c', 'chcp&dir /B h*.txt'], shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
  print(line.decode('utf-8').strip())

process.stdout.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost the solution, however not exactly. Please, see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2016.9, module `subprocess` [version 3.6](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/050acaed9926aa0a0367ec1baebbfd797c33ad74) has `encoding` parameter in function `subprocess.run()`, so that you can set specified encoding.

So, if you **don't want** to change the encoding of the CMD:

1. Type `chcp` in your CMD and get the active code page.
   e.g. `936`.
2. Get the encoding from [Code Page Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers).
   Identifier(`936`): .NET Name(`gb2312`)
3. `gb2312` is the encoding name python can recognize for the most cases. But you can check the [Standard Encodings of Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) to be sure, thanks to [Mark Amery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25584253/5340217).
4. Add `encoding='gb2312'` to your `subprocess.run()` function.

   `process_list = subprocess.run('dir', shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, text=True, encoding='gb2312').stdout.split('\n')[:-1]`
5. The `subprocess.Popen` constructor also has `encoding` parameter if you really want to stick to `Popen`, while it's [recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=recomendded#using-the-subprocess-module) that "The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the `run()` function for all use cases it can handle."

If you **want** to change the encoding of the CMD, refer to the answer by [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67533056/5340217).